# Printing in new window in FireFox doesn't work the first time, but afterwards

Tags: javascript

My script should open a window and trigger the print dialog 2s after that. The script always opens the popup and the print dialog, but the first time it doesn't work to really print (e.g. to PDF) the document, although it does every other time.

```js
function PrintElem(elem) {
  var mywindow = window.open('', 'PRINT', 'height=130px,width=250px');
  mywindow.document.write('<html><head>');
  mywindow.document.write('</head><body >');
  mywindow.document.write(document.getElementById(elem).innerHTML);
  mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');
  mywindow.document.close(); // necessary for IE >= 10
  mywindow.focus(); // necessary for IE >= 10*/
  setTimeout(function() {
    mywindow.print();
    mywindow.close();
  }, 2000)
  return true;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyDiv">
  <p>Some Text</p>
</div>
<a id="12345" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="PrintElem('MyDiv');return false;">Print MyDiv</a>
```

Comment: I just made [a plnkr out of your script](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cc6JUGn5NY56m4PB), you want to open the content of the div in a new window and print it, right? Works for me every time I click on the link.
What browser are you testing on? What exactly happens the first time, could you check the console, please?

Comment: Firefox latest version :( tested on two pc. Only the first time after browser opening the script don't work in my case.

Comment: i tried, same problem. How to check console?

Comment: You may check the console you see when pressing F12 an switching to the console-tab in there. Nevertheless, seems that you got detected by some popup-blockers; is there any hint on that in the url-bar or somewhere else? In my very own case, FF doesn't block the link in the plnkr linked above - not even the first time. So sorry, not reproductible for me. Maybe check the plugins - ad-blockers may fiddle around with that, too.

Comment: To reproduce the problem you must try to print! the popup window opens perfectly to me too. Even the first time and forever. It is the print that does not go to the printer the first time after opening the browser. From the second time I launch the print always works. Try printing something in pdf to reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this line `mywindow.document.close();` is causing the issue. It should be after `mywindow.document.print();`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you now clarified that your script is triggering the window and the print-popup correctly, but only the Printing itself in FF doesn't work as expected the first time, I reasearched a bit.

It's an old closed issue, but there at least is one regarding FF not printing the first time. [An comment suggests to delay the close-operation](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=351581#c88) by some time (e.g. 1s).

It seems you have to delay the close-operation, because otherwise for some reasons FF doesn't know what window to print since it's closed too early. [See my plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/9ohymJxLe3Z24ycc).

So this is gonna help:

```js
mywindow.print();
setTimeout(function() {
    mywindow.close();
}, 5000)
```